# Using string instead array of bytes java

Tags: java, database, string

Can I use string instead array of bytes made with new String(bytes)? I whant to save them to database. In bytes I have calculated md5 hash.

Comment: what is the problem with array, sir?

Comment: What about [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a `String` is not suitable as a container for arbitrary bytes.

The `String(byte[] bytes)` constructor will interpret the array that you pass to it and convert it to characters, using the default character encoding of your system. This might throw an exception if the byte array contains a sequence of bytes which is not valid for the character encoding, and even if it works without an exception then calling `getBytes()` on the `String` is not guaranteed to return the exact same bytes.

If you want to store a byte array in a database, store it as a BLOB (Binary Large OBject), or, if you really want to store it as a string, then convert it into text using for example Base64 encoding or as hexadecimal digits.